# On website load: ReferenceError: process is not defined

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs3, vite, mime

I've just installed my Debian 11 server from OVH. I installed NodeJS 18.16.1 and cloned my project. I get no error when I run the npm install, but when I start my vue3 project with vite, it gives me the following error:

```
mime.js:25 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at Mime.define (mime.js:25:7)
    at node_modules/mime/mime.js (mime.js:87:6)
    at __require2 (chunk-6NOISVLF.js?v=f8646329:16:50)
    at node_modules/send/index.js (index.js:24:12)
    at __require2 (chunk-6NOISVLF.js?v=f8646329:16:50)
    at node_modules/express/lib/utils.js (utils.js:20:12)
    at __require2 (chunk-6NOISVLF.js?v=f8646329:16:50)
    at node_modules/express/lib/application.js (application.js:24:19)
    at __require2 (chunk-6NOISVLF.js?v=f8646329:16:50)
    at node_modules/express/lib/express.js (express.js:18:13)
```

Locally I have no problem.

```
{
  "name": "campo-frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "run-p type-check build-only",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "build-only": "vite build",
    "host": "vite --host",
    "type-check": "vue-tsc --noEmit -p tsconfig.app.json --composite false",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .vue,.js,.jsx,.cjs,.mjs,.ts,.tsx,.cts,.mts --fix --ignore-path .gitignore",
    "format": "prettier --write src/"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^3.0.3",
    "@johmun/vue-tags-input": "^2.1.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
    "@vuepic/vue-datepicker": "^5.4.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.0",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.23.1",
    "bulma": "^0.9.4",
    "bulma-calendar": "^6.1.19",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.8",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "moment-weekday-calc": "^1.1.4",
    "qs": "^6.11.2",
    "safe-buffer": "^5.2.1",
    "sass": "^1.62.1",
    "vue": "^3.3.2",
    "vue-router": "^4.2.0",
    "vue-toast-notification": "3.0",
    "vuex": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.7",
    "@rushstack/eslint-patch": "^1.2.0",
    "@tsconfig/node18": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/node": "^18.16.8",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.2.3",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^7.1.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^11.0.3",
    "@vue/tsconfig": "^0.4.0",
    "eslint": "^8.39.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.11.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "postcss": "^8.4.24",
    "postcss-cli": "^10.1.0",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "typescript": "~5.0.4",
    "vite": "^4.3.5",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.6.4"
  }
}
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling node but nothing changes.

Comment: How is express related to vue app? The error means that express was bundled to run in a browser, while it certainly shouldn't

Comment: It was because I was using the Express Response type to type my axios response but I just removed Express and it worked. Thanks!!